# Ubuntu 20.04 on i386 computer

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my USB-stick and when I want to run it on i386 architecture computer, GRUB rescue shows up and I can not boot it from there, problably because of architecture.

What should I do?
If there is need of any more informations, tell me which ones and where to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't support 32-bit CPUs since version 17.10 (released 4 years ago).

Some flavors of previous LTS version of Ubuntu, that is 18.04, may support it. For example Ubuntu Budgie and Lubuntu do provide 32-bit versions.

Comment: It might be worth noting there are lots of distros out there that do support 32-bit architecture, although that number drops every year... That said, a PC that is purely 32-bit is quite old (almost all PC's have been 64-bit since the mid 2000's) and could really have issues in day to day usage as a typical daily use machine.

Comment: Intel and AMD are quickly moving to products that while they can run 32-bit software they likely will be unable to boot 32-bit operating systems due to the fact only 64-bit UEFI kernels will be offered. There is a reason only a 64-bit version of Windows 11 is offered and it was only partially due to Microsoft making that decision.